# python and combining a multidimensional list (opencv)

Tags: python, list, opencv, merge

I am a bit new to python/opencv and i am kind of confused. I guess my problem has nothing to do with opencv and is just python. So i will explain it without the opencv stuff:
I have a 3-dim list:

```
for contour in contours:
    contour = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,10,True)
    print "--------------------------"
    print contour
    print "--------------------------"
```

and i get this:

```
--------------------------
[[[168 377]]

 [[250 404]]]
--------------------------
--------------------------
[[[332 153]]

 [[419 216]]]
--------------------------
```

But, what i really want is this:

```
--------------------------
[[[168 377]]

 [[250 404]]

 [[332 153]]

 [[419 216]]]
--------------------------
```

When i am building the list by oy own its also working, the way it shoud:

```
>>> np.array([[[168,377],[250,404],[332,153],[419,216]]])
array([[[168, 377],
        [250, 404],
        [332, 153],
        [419, 216]]])
```

I know... The dimensions are not the same. I have no clue why opencv can handle this!? (These are contours out of `cv2.findContours`
Anyone knows how to rearrange this list? Or a useful doc for this.
Thanks und Greets :)

Comment: they are numpy arrays, you can look up lots of useful stuff if you search with numpy as keyword or on numpy documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = []
for contour in contours:
    contour = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,10,True)
    print "--------------------------"
    print contour
    print "--------------------------"
    res.append(contour)
print np.vstack(res)
```

Comment: While the posted might solve the problem, it is also better to provide some explanation. They can help future readers.

Comment: Thanks Zaw! This solved the decribed problem. But unfortunately not my "real" problem ;)

Comment: To use this new combined array as a continuous contour you have to use it as `cv2.drawContours(drawing,[np.vstack(combined)],0,color,1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(2):
    tempcnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    tempcnts = imutils.grab_contours(tempcnts)
    # tempcnts = cv2.approxPolyDP(tempcnts, 10, True)
    print("--------------------------")
    print(tempcnts)
    print("--------------------------")
    if i==0:
        cnts=tempcnts
    else:
        cnts[0]=np.append(cnts[0], tempcnts[0],0)
print("--------------------------")
print("--------------------------")
print("--------------------------")
print(cnts)
print("--------------------------")
print("--------------------------")
print("--------------------------")
```